# Remove model admin search/filter options if not an admin

Tags: silverstripe

I want to be able to hide the search/filter options that are provided by the model admin if the user that logs in is not an admin.

Currently we have a "Photographer" permission setup and don't want them to be able to use/see these filters.

Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can define `searchableFields` procedurally.

```
class MyDataObject .... 
{
  public function searchableFields()
  {
    if($someCondition) return;
    return parent::searchableFields();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @UncleCheese, I was using `scaffoldSearchFields()` so have applied the same thing on that, I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the `scaffoldSearchFields()` so I took @UncleCheese way and applied that to it which gave me the result I was after:

```
public function scaffoldSearchFields($_params = null) {
        $fields = parent::scaffoldSearchFields($_params);

        $salesRegionDropdown = DropdownField::create(
            'SalesRegion',
            'Sales Region',
            SalesRegion::get()->map('ID', 'Region')->toArray()
        )->setEmptyString('-- Please choose a sales region --');

        $fields->replaceField('SalesRegion', $salesRegionDropdown);

        .....

        if (!Permission::check('ADMIN')) {
            return false;
        }

        return $fields;
    }
```